# Reducing Django Memory Usage. Low hanging fruit?

Tags: python, django, profiling, memory-management, mod-python

My memory usage increases over time and restarting Django is not kind to users.

I am unsure how to go about profiling the memory usage but some tips on how to start measuring would be useful.

I have a feeling that there are some simple steps that could produce big gains. Ensuring 'debug' is set to 'False' is an obvious biggie.

Can anyone suggest others? How much improvement would caching on low-traffic sites?

In this case I'm running under Apache 2.x with mod_python. I've heard mod_wsgi is a bit leaner but it would be tricky to switch at this stage unless I know the gains would be significant.

Edit: Thanks for the tips so far. Any suggestions how to discover what's using up the memory? Are there any guides to Python memory profiling?

Also as mentioned there's a few things that will make it tricky to switch to mod_wsgi so I'd like to have some idea of the gains I could expect before ploughing forwards in that direction.

**Edit:** Carl posted a slightly more detailed reply here that is worth reading: [Django Deployment: Cutting Apache's Overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488864/django-deployment-cutting-apaches-overhead)

**Edit:** [Graham Dumpleton's article](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html) is the best I've found on the MPM and mod_wsgi related stuff. I am rather disappointed that no-one could provide any info on debugging the memory usage in the app itself though.

**Final Edit:** Well I have been discussing this with Webfaction to see if they could assist with recompiling Apache and this is their word on the matter:

> "I really don't think that you will get much of a benefit by switching to an MPM Worker + mod_wsgi setup.  I estimate that you might be able to save around 20MB, but probably not much more than that."

So! This brings me back to my original question (which I am still none the wiser about). How does one go about identifying where the problems lies? It's a well known maxim that you don't optimize without testing to see where you need to optimize but there is very little in the way of tutorials on measuring Python memory usage and none at all specific to Django.

Thanks for everyone's assistance but I think this question is still open!

**Another final edit ;-)**

I asked this on the django-users list and got some [*very* helpful replies](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/1d56d48fc192ceed?fwc=1&pli=1)

**Honestly the last update ever!**

This was just released. Could be the best solution yet: [Profiling Django object size and memory usage with Pympler](https://rk.edu.pl/en/profiling-django-object-size-and-memory-usage-pympler/)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Make sure you are not keeping global references to data. That prevents the python garbage collector from releasing the memory.

Don't use `mod_python`. It loads an interpreter inside apache. If you need to use apache, use [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead. It is not tricky to switch. It is very easy. `mod_wsgi` is way easier to [configure for django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) than brain-dead `mod_python`.

If you can remove apache from your requirements, that would be even better to your memory. [`spawning`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning/0.7) seems to be the new fast scalable way to run python web applications.

**EDIT**: I don't see how switching to mod_wsgi could be "*tricky*". It should be a very easy task. Please elaborate on the problem you are having with the switch.

Comment: Django developers advocate using mod_python don't they? What's wrong with using Apache?

Comment: @Josh: apache's bloat and memory usage is stupid if you're not using apache-only features. It just an unnecessary layer.

Comment: Django still endorses mod_python because mod_wsgi is still fairly new, and they want to be conservative.  But if you follow the Django community you'll see people switching to mod_wsgi en masse.  It won't take long before it's the recommended option.

Comment: @nosklo: What would be an apache-only feature, for example?

I'm finishing my app, and I'm starting to worry about deploying... and, as I never deployed  django before, I studying all the possibilities.

Comment: @Tiago: apache is good when you have a lot of apache virtual hosts already in place, using SSL with apache already, etc. In this case, use mod_wsgi. If you are starting afresh, use spawning. NEVER use mod_python.

Comment: re switching to mod_wsgi I've got some code for authenticating static content requests against Django permissions and I haven't found an equivalent for mod_wsgi. Also I would like to avoid migrating 10 production websites if at all possible as I'm a believer in 'if it ain't broke...'

Comment: Thanks, nosklo. I'm taking a look at spawning.. seems to have little to none documentation.. I'll try to follow some instructions I found in blog posts and see where I can get.

Comment: @Tiago: maybe ask a new top-level question about it - it is not hard to setup.

Comment: @andybak: if your auth system is written as django middleware, or called inside a django urls.py I don't see why it wouldn't work with mod_wsgi.

Comment: @nosklo It's static files I want to control so requests won't even see Django unless I tie in with the webservers own auth mechanism (and it has to be cookie based as a HTTP auth dialog isn't very pretty for my users)

Comment: Hmm, as someone just starting to use Django, I'll keep in mind that I should use mod_wsgi.

Comment: Don't use mod_python or mod_wsgi. Use standalone django servers with a lean front-end like nginx or lighttpd and FastCGI proxying :)

Comment: @nezroy: that's a highly debatable recommendation.  I would say that  WSGI, an actively-developed standard with a booming ecosystem of middleware etc, has much more of a future in Python web application deployment than FastCGI.

Comment: @andybak: then use mod_python for your apache auth extension module, and mod_wsgi to run your django application.

Answer (score 28):

If you are running under mod_wsgi, and presumably spawning since it is WSGI compliant, you can use [Dozer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dozer) to look at your memory usage.

Under mod_wsgi just add this at the bottom of your WSGI script:

```
from dozer import Dozer
application = Dozer(application)
```

Then point your browser at http://domain/_dozer/index to see a list of all your memory allocations.

I'll also just add my voice of support for mod_wsgi.  It makes a world of difference in terms of performance and memory usage over mod_python.  Graham Dumpleton's support for mod_wsgi is outstanding, both in terms of active development and in helping people on the mailing list to optimize their installations.  David Cramer at [curse.com](http://www.curse.com/) has posted some charts (which I can't seem to find now unfortunately) showing the drastic reduction in cpu and memory usage after they switched to mod_wsgi on that high traffic site.  Several of the django devs have switched.  Seriously, it's a no-brainer :)

Comment: In which case I will soon be posting a question asking how one gets cookie based authentication for django users accessing static files...

Answer (score 15):

These are the Python memory profiler solutions I'm aware of (not Django related):

- [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy)
- [pysizer](http://pysizer.8325.org/) (discontinued)
- <strike>Python Memory Validator (commercial)</strike>
- [Pympler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler)

Disclaimer: I have a stake in the latter.

The individual project's documentation should give you an idea of how to use these tools to analyze memory behavior of Python applications.

The following is a nice "war story" that also gives some helpful pointers:

- [Reducing the footprint of python applications](http://wingolog.org/archives/2007/11/27/reducing-the-footprint-of-python-applications)

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, check if you do not use any of known leakers. MySQLdb is known to leak enormous amounts of memory with Django due to bug in unicode handling. Other than that, [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master) might help you to track the hogs.

Comment: http://amix.dk/blog/viewEntry/19420 shows dozer being used to show that MySQLdb was leaking memory. MySQLdb 1.2.3c1 and later fixes this.

Comment: How could `django-debug-toolbar` help?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to not keeping around global references to large data objects, try to avoid loading large datasets into memory at all wherever possible.

Switch to mod_wsgi in daemon mode, and use Apache's worker mpm instead of prefork.  This latter step can allow you to serve many more concurrent users with much less memory overhead.

Comment: Also see Carl's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488864/django-deployment-cutting-apaches-overhead

Comment: Also - in a few posts I've read it seems that the real gain is in switching to worker MPM rather than the use of mod_wsgi...

Answer (score 4):

Webfaction actually has [some tips](http://blog.webfaction.com/tips-to-keep-your-django-mod-python-memory-usage-down) for keeping django memory usage down.

The major points:

- Make sure debug is set to false (you already know that).
- Use "ServerLimit" in your apache config
- Check that no big objects are being loaded in memory
- Consider serving static content in a separate process or server.
- Use "MaxRequestsPerChild" in your apache config
- Find out and understand how much memory you're using

Comment: Thanks, I had already read those. It's numbers 3 and 6 I was hoping for a bit more detail on! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another plus for mod_wsgi: set a `maximum-requests` parameter in your `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive and mod_wsgi will restart the daemon process every so often. There should be no visible effect for the user, other than a slow page load the first time a fresh process is hit, as it'll be loading Django and your application code into memory.

But even if you *do* have memory leaks, that should keep the process size from getting too large, without having to interrupt service to your users.

Comment: Something similar is mentioned here: http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg84698.html

only they used inactivity-timeout instead of maximum-requests.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the script I use for mod_wsgi (called wsgi.py, and put in the root off my django project):

```
import os
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

from os import path

sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'a+')
sys.stderr = open('/dev/null', 'a+')

sys.path.append(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Adjust myproject.settings and the path as needed. I redirect all output to /dev/null since mod_wsgi by default prevents printing. Use logging instead.

For apache:

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName myhost.com

   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-myhost.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-myhost.log common

   DocumentRoot "/var/www"

   WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully this should at least help you set up mod_wsgi so you can see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Caches: make sure they're being flushed.  Its easy for something to land in a cache, but never be GC'd because of the cache reference.

Swig'd code: Make sure any memory management is being done correctly, its really easy to miss these in python, especially with third party libraries

Monitoring: If you can, get data about memory usage and hits.  Usually you'll see a correlation between a certain type of request and memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

We stumbled over a bug in Django with big sitemaps (10.000 items). Seems Django is trying to load them all in memory when generating the sitemap: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11572 - effectively kills the apache process when Google pays a visit to the site.